# Validating a string to be all digits

Tags: c++, string

Hi I'm having trouble validating this string to be all decimals, even if I type in 9999 it still tell me my if statement comes out false. I think it's a typo but I don't know where.

```
cout<<"Enter a very large number"<<endl;
cin>>In1;                            //inputs a string
for(int i=0; 0<In1.length();i++){    //the loop that goes thru each index
    if (!(isdigit(In1[i]))){         //validates each index
        //tells the user to try again
        cout<<"You did not enter a valid input, please try again"<<endl;
        In1="";
        cin>>In1;
        i=0;//starts the loop over if reached
    }
}
```

I keep receiving the "You did not enter a valid input, please try again" regardless of whether I type it right or wrong.

Comment: In1 is a string. It's meant to be that way, not an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; 0<In1.length();i++){
```

See what you did? Change to

```
for(int i=0; i<In1.length();i++)
```

In your loop condition you need to compare `i` with `In1.length()`.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to change

```
0<In1.length()
```

to

```
i<In1.length()
```

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
#include<algorithm>

if ( std::find_not_if( in1.begin(), in1.end(), isdigit ) != in1.end() ){ ...
```

might have prevented this unfortunate incident, and is also quite clear on the intent. The dual _not/!= muddles it slightly but still.

There are quite a few convenience algorithms, replacing common uses for simple for- statements.  Most of them are on the form

```
do_this( where_to_start, where_to_end, do_this_operation )
```

There is usually nothing special or dramatic with these function, they apply the operation to each element in the start-end sequence.

You have `find`, `count`, `copy`, and `generate` to mention a few.  Their purpose is to clarify the intent of your for-statement.   You can find a complete list at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: I'm new to c++ can you explain a little bit of what's happening?

Comment: @OPJ Added a little info

Answer (score 2):

You will almost certainly find that, over time, you become more adept at seperating different parts of code into the functionality that they each provide. Making debugging and later modification considerably easier.

It also makes, as Captain Giraffe points out, the intent of the code considerably more clear - something that can only make reading the code easier & quicker.

I've not used std::find_not_if, opting instead to use the method that you've chosen (based on the assumption that the important thing is *knowing* how to get the right answer, as opposed to simply supplying *the right answer* - well, that *and* me not knowing of `find_not_if`'s existence :grin:) You'll see that I've chucked it into it's own function, which I call from main. The function also only performs a single task - that of checking the validity of the string. Any attempt to prompt the user for this text, re-prompt in the case of error and finally, take action on the correct input is the sole responsibility of the code that calls `isValidNumericalString` - there's no reason you couldn't throw those functions into their own functions, as opposed to having a single, large body of main.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// returns true if all characters in string are numerical (0-9)
bool isValidNumericalString(string inputString)
{
    int i, n = inputString.length();
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        if ( !isdigit(inputString[i]) )
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    string In1;

    cout << "Enter a very large number (digits 0-9 only. 10e1 is unacceptable): ";
    cin >> In1;

    while (!isValidNumericalString(In1))
    {
        cout << "You did not enter a valid input, please try again :p" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a very large number (digits 0-9 only. 10e1 is unacceptable): ";
        cin >> In1;
    }

    cout << "Congratulations - '" << In1 << "' is a valid string representation of a number" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```